# fastest way to store load data with app with threadx in stm32

Tags: c, rtos, threadx

I am looking for the fastest way to store data(about 50kb) with the applciation code during the flashing process and load it to be use by the application or by the kernel of the RTOS,
I am using RTOS called ThreadX in STM32H7,

the stored small data will determie how the application behave

Note: I tried to use FileX(extension for ThreadX), but it should format the NOR Flash first to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is too vague. What speed do you need? What do you mean by store and load data? How small is "very small?"

For volatile data, just store it in the on-chip ram. For non volatile data, you have many options - write to the on-chip flash is probably the fastest.

Comment: Using on-chip flash can be awkward and wasteful for small data.  The flash needs to be erased before it can be overwritten with new data and, often, data can only be erased in large blocks, 4k+, so wasteful for a few bytes of data.  Another issue is that erases can be lengthy operations and run with interrupts disabled, (ie. dead zone for a thread tasker:).

Comment: @MartinJames the data will be used by the application, and it would be great if it will be stored along with the app code in the on-chip flash